# How to render html as text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
<td>
   @(vehicle.SearchResult.Mpg == null ? 
     Html.Raw("<a href='Model.ContactDealerUrl'>Please Contact Dealer</a>") : 
     vehicle.SearchResult.Mpg + " " + Html.GetResourceTranslation("UclMpg").ToHtmlString())
</td>
```

Hi, I'm new to stack overflow but I'm trying to render the html tag as a link text, such as 'Please Contact Dealer' but when rendered unto the browser returns as 'Please Contact Dealer'. Any help on how to fix this will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain your issue a bit more? I do not understand what the problem is.

Comment: The Html which returns when the condition is true returns exactly as it is in the Html.Raw parameter, I am trying to get it to return the string "Please Contact Dealer" as a link but instead it returns the entire string, ancor tags and the all @JeffSiver

Comment: Were you trying to bold the Html.Raw part in your question, or are the double asterisks actually in your razor view file?  Otherwise, I don't see any problems.  The Raw should return the HTML as a clickable link.

Comment: Try replacing  vehicle.SearchResult.Mpg + " " + Html.GetResourceTranslation("UclMpg").ToHtmlString()   with just:    Html.Raw("")   to see if that part is causing the problem.

Comment: I was trying to bold it @seagulledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem, following details may help you fix the behavior.

If your original code looks like:

```
@Html.Raw("<a href='Model.ContactDealerUrl'>Please Contact Dealer</a>").ToHtmlString()
```

then remove the `ToHtmlString()` and make else part in the conditional expression also to return `IHtmlString` (label/link etc., element).

If `ToHtmlString()` on `@Html.Raw(...)` is called then it render the raw Html string instead of element.

Invalid: `@(some condition? IHtmlString : string)`. In a conditional expression the true/false return `Type` should be same or implicitly convertible.

Hope this help you...